# Matlab decimate(vector, order, 'fir') internal workings

Tags: c, matlab, filtering, translate

Does anyone know what specific function is being used to determine the filter coefficients in `decimate(vector, order, 'fir')` ? Specifically is it `fir1` with `Wn = 0.5`? It says the order is 30, so that's for certain. I got these coefficients, but I can't duplicate the results in `decimate`.

```
C = fir1(30, 0.5)

-1.6994e-03 8.8095e-05 2.9361e-03 ... 2.9361e-03 8.8095e-05 -1.6994e-03
```

I'm trying to translate MatLab code to C and coming up against a lack of documentation.

Comment: Do you have access to this book? IEEE® Programs for Digital Signal Processing, IEEE Press. New York: John Wiley & Sons, 1979.

Comment: Btw, according to [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/decimate.html), the input variables are like this: `decimate(vector,factor,'fir')` (default order of `30`) or `decimate(vector,factor,order,'fir')` (now the `order` can be manipulated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed using source code from Octave that the filter is `fir1(30, 1/order)`.

Answer (score 0):

fir1 uses as cut off frequency, a normalized number between 0:1. Since the effect in frequency of decimation is to 'expand' the signal spectrum by a factor of r, what the fir1 does is to assure that after the expansion, the signal still lies between the normalized frequency of 0:1.
I tried the code also with cconv for applying the filter to my signal. After comparison with decimate function, it showed a phase delay. Then I tried with filtfilt and the phase delay disappeared.

```
lx = length(x);
filt = fir1(30,1/r);
w = filtfilt(filt,1,x);
y = zeros(1,lx/r);
for i=1:lx/r
    y(i) = w(r*i);
end
```